# Is there a configuration setting to automatically display jenkins console output

Tags: jenkins

When I manually execute a jenkins job, it would save an annoying step if, upon submitting the build button, the next screen was the console output and not the project page.

Is there a configuration setting that allows this to happen?

Comment: Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

No native option of that kind I guess. Recent jenkins builds allow a shorter way to access console output - just click on the gray/blue point left to the currently running build:

[image: One click access to Console output]
If you still think one click is annoying extra step, then next option I'd suggest is using jenkins CLI. It needs some more one-time effort though.

1. Have java installed on your workstation
2. Download jenkins-cli.jar from http://*your jenkins host*/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar

Then you can start builds like that:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins-url  build buildname  -w -s -v  -p parameterN=valueN



java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -noKeyAuth -s http://jet:8080  build tst-so  -w -s -v  -p host2ping=google.com 
Started tst-so #17
Started from command line by anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tst-so/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5079113569382475588.sh
+ echo Hello from tst-so job
Hello from tst-so job
+ ping -c 6 google.com
PING google.com (216.58.209.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=51.6 ms
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=51.9 ms
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=51.8 ms
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=51.8 ms
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=51.8 ms
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=51.7 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 51.684/51.815/51.900/0.306 ms
Finished: SUCCESS
Completed tst-so #17 : SUCCESS
```

In my example jenkins is setup with no authentication for simplicity reason.

Comment: Wow, that's an unexpected shortcut. Click the build status to go to console output!